# creating a pomodoro timer google chrome extension, and the play button always resets the clock instead of just playing from current stop time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, countdowntimer

i'm creating a pomodoro timer chrome extension and i'm relatively new to programming. This js code from my focus_time page has issues with the play button...whenever you click play it resets the button instead of starting from whatever the stop time shows. Is the issue here? or somewhere else do you think?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let countdown;
  let focusRound = 1;
  let focusDuration;
  let restDuration;
  let focusRounds;
  let isPaused = false;

  const focusTimeDisplay = document.getElementById('timer');
  const playBtn = document.getElementById('playBtnFocus');
  const pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pauseBtn');
  const stopResetBtn = document.getElementById('stop-reset');
  const focusIterationDisplay = document.getElementById('focusIteration');

  chrome.storage.local.get(['focusTime', 'restTime', 'rounds'], (result) => {
    focusDuration = result.focusTime;
    restDuration = result.restTime;
    focusRounds = result.rounds;

    focusTimeDisplay.textContent = formatTime(focusDuration);
    focusIterationDisplay.textContent = `Focus ${focusRound} / ${focusRounds}`;

    playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (!countdown) {
        startFocus();
      } else if (isPaused) {
        resumeCountdown();
      }
    });

    pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (countdown) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        countdown = null;
        isPaused = true;
      }
    });

    stopResetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (countdown) {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        countdown = null;
        isPaused = false;
      } else {
        focusTimeDisplay.textContent = formatTime(focusDuration);
      }
    });

    // Start the countdown immediately
    startFocus();
  });

  function startFocus() {
    countdown = createCountdown(focusDuration, focusTimeDisplay, () => {
      playSound('stopsound.wav');
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (focusRound < focusRounds) {
          focusRound++;
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'startRest' });
          window.close();
        } else {
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'showCongratulations' });
          window.close();
        }
      }, 1000);
    });

    focusIterationDisplay.textContent = `Focus ${focusRound} / ${focusRounds}`;

    playSound('startsound.wav');
  }

  function resumeCountdown() {
    countdown = createCountdown(getRemainingTime(), focusTimeDisplay, () => {
      playSound('stopsound.wav');
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (focusRound < focusRounds) {
          focusRound++;
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'startRest' });
          window.close();
        } else {
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'showCongratulations' });
          window.close();
        }
      }, 1000);
    });

    playSound('startsound.wav');
  }

  function createCountdown(duration, display, callback) {
    let timeRemaining = duration;
    display.textContent = formatTime(timeRemaining);

    const countdownInterval = setInterval(() => {
      timeRemaining--;

      if (timeRemaining < 0) {
        clearInterval(countdownInterval);
        callback();
      } else {
        display.textContent = formatTime(timeRemaining);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return countdownInterval;
  }

  function formatTime(seconds) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    seconds %= 60;

    return `${minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}:${seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')}`;
  }

  function playSound(filename) {
    const audio = new Audio(chrome.runtime.getURL(filename));
   

audio.play();
}
});
```

Everything i've tried simply keeps the clock from auto starting when the focus time popup pops up. The functionality is that the clock auto-starts when this pop-up engages (which it does now)..and then after you hit pause or stop-reset, the play button should restart the clock from the stopped time. In this code the play button resets the clock and restarts from the user selection value

Comment: In playBtn.addEventListener check first  if (isPaused) { ... and after if (!countdown) {...